# Help Finding a Fantasy (I think) novel - It Had A Snake eating its Tail on the Cover

Tags: story-identification

Never fear I can in fact remember more about it than that! The cover was black and it had a silver snake eating its own tail on the cover. The book was about a boy who is hired by a company to travel (with a girl and another boy (the drummer)) to another world/alternative reality and there they discovered another girl who turned out to be his dead twin sister.

He was some hero or something and they found something out about the company they were hired by and at one point he was almost killed but got a scar next to his right (or maybe left) eye that made him or marked him as the seer? His twin gave him a bracelet shaped like a snake biting its own tail and that meant something important... The Snake was also the symbol/logo of the company.

In the end he went home and spoke to him mom about his twin and I remember it being the first book in a series.

Comment: Adamant may have found the answer, the same as the book at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33464/looking-for-young-adult-book-possible-from-the-last-10-15-years

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You found it!!! Thank you :) This is indeed the right book. Didn't know it was a translation though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your description Just Searched google and look what I found.

### For anyone looking for title its "PROPHECY OF THE SISTERS"

[This](http://beverlyrivera.blogspot.in/2014/01/day-9-of-sisters-by-michelle-zink.html) can be your book.

> An ancient prophecy divides two sisters- 
>   One good... 
>   One evil... 
>   Who will prevail? 
>   Twin sisters Lia and Alice Milthorpe have just become orphans. They have also become enemies. As they discover their roles in a prophecy that has turned generations of sisters against each other, the girls find themselves entangled in a mystery that involves a tattoo-like mark, their parents' deaths, a boy, a book, and a lifetime of secrets. 
>   Lia and Alice don't know whom they can trust.
>  
>   They just know they can't trust each other.

[image: Book cover under the jacket]

Comment: How does it match the description? Where's the snake on the cover??

Comment: if you see the second image from the link... the hard covered one

Comment: I think user14111 is suggesting that you add the details that match, and the image. :) Editing your own post is pretty painless and the insert picture button allows you to paste the URL of the image in.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Done.

Comment: The ourobouros is a match, but the plot doesn't seem to match...

Comment: Yeah the protagonist was definitely a boy with there only being to girls in the story both unrelated.

Comment: @Rincewind The blurb mentions a boy, which might be who you're thinking of as the protaganist, and it also mentions a tattoo-like mark which could be the scar you mention in your question. Definitely some other details that don't match.

Comment: But yeah, the one linked in the comment on the answer definitely sounds like a closer match.

Comment: Yeah it is definitely The Dream Merchant. Thanks @FuzzyBoots!